# Prove there does not exist $(a, b, c, d)$, not all $0$, such that $ a^2 + b^2 = 3(c^2+d^2)$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that there is no quadruplet of integers $(a, b, c, d)$, not all $0$, such that:
> $$ a^2 + b^2 = 3(c^2+d^2)$$

I would appreciate a solution for this problem or a hint please.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be highly appreciated if you include your research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is valid.

Note that all perfect squares are $0, 1 \pmod 3$; so, $a \equiv b \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ because the RHS is a multiple of $3$. Set $a=3x$, $b=3y$. Then we have $9(x^2+y^2)=3(c^2+d^2)$, or $3(x^2+y^2)=c^2+d^2$. Then we set $c=3p$ and $3r$ and so on. This gives that $a,b$ must have an infinite number of factors of $3$, which is obviously not possible. Hence proved. $\blacksquare$

Comment: You can avoid “infinite factors” arguments like this by using the well-ordering principle, saying: Assume there exists a solution. Let $n$ be the smallest $n$ such that $n=x^2+y^2=3(c^2+d^2)$for some  integers, not all zero, $x,y,c,d.$ (Since all such $n$ are natural, there is a least example.) Then use your answer to show that $n/3$ is a smaller.

Answer (score 0):

take (mod 3) both sides then, ${a^2+b^2 \equiv 0 (mod3)}$. Now, ${1^2 \equiv 1 (mod3)}$, ${2^2 \equiv 1 (mod 3)}$, i.e., equation can be satisfy if a and b both are 0. But that is a constraint you mentiond. hence euqation doesn't have any solution in  ${Z}$